# Solr 4.10 Index file with ignore error doc

Tags: indexing, solr

In solr file indexing:

File contain multiple doc.

While index a file (xml or json) Can we ignore particular doc if error existing and remaining doc can post to solr?

Comment: Are you using Solrj or SimplePostTool or something else (e.g. DIH)?

Comment: Using curl to post xml / json file

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe post.sh offers this option. It is supposed to be a *Simple* Post tool.

I suggest you to write a simple client using Solrj or a client API in your favourite language.